# C# Apply DateTimeKind to a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

Given that DateTime.Kind is a get-only property, how do we assign DateTimeKind to a DateTime object that's born out of DateTime.Parse()?

```
var dte = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2018 10:10:00");

Console.WriteLine("{0} | Kind: {1}", dte, dte.Kind.ToString());

// PRINTS: 1/1/2018 10:10:00 AM | Kind: Unspecified

dte = dte.ToLocalTime();

Console.WriteLine("{0} | Kind: {1}", dte, dte.Kind.ToString());

// PRINTS: 1/1/2018 6:10:00 PM | Kind: Local
// OK, the "Kind" is changed to "Local" which is what I'm trying to achieve 
// however it also converted the time!!!
```

My question is how to apply Utc or Local "Kind" to the object dte without using dte.ToUniversal() or dte.ToLocal() because both method converts (or changes) the time

Comment: Consider passing `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` for UTC time or  `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` for local time, to do this during the parsing phase rather than after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a new DateTime with the DateTimeKind you want, by using the parsed datetime, and a constructor that takes DateTimeKind, like the following:
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: After my question was marked as duplicate, I found the answer (almost similar to your answer) from the link provided by Ivan Stoev. Thank you!